# SoapUI Load Test Limit

Tags: soapui, load-testing

Is there a limit to load test limits with the free version of SoapUI? I was able to run the default load test whose limit is 10 seconds, but what I really need is to run it for an hour. However, every time I try to set the limit for 3600 seconds, it keeps getting reset to 3.600 seconds. Am I making a rookie mistake or is the free version working as designed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm aware only of 9999 threads limit, the dot (or comma) you're seeing is only a delimiter for better readability, it will appear for the next 3 digits.

[image]

If it is sufficient for your needs - go ahead, if not - I would recommend considering switching to [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) as it has [much better reporting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), [more flexible in defining workload patterns](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) and can go much above 10 000 threads (virtual users) especially given [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/) feature